# laravel4 Request::get api documentation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i have 5+ yrs of experience on java but i am new to php and laravel both 
I am trying to explore laravel api documentation to get "Request::get" documentation but not able to get it. pls any one suggest the right way to explore api documentation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  For instance, are you trying to make a GET request?  ..Or handle an incoming GET?  ...Or route a GET?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any `get` method usable as it in `Request`. If you want to grab GET or POST inputs from a form or AJAX, use `Input::get` => http://laravel.com/docs/requests

Answer (score 0):

Just use the search function on the Laravel API docs: http://laravel.com/api

Here is what you need: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Http.Request.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but i am unable to get "get" method here.